# System.NullReferenceException ao enviar Form Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho um controller de editar, que recebe um valor do banco e joga pra view, e depois eu quero com essa view jogar os valores na tela (teste basico)...

Porém, mesmo com meu controller que leva pra view de edita passando um objeto **Filial**, ele me diz que filial está nulo. Segue abaixo meu controller e minha view:

```
public ActionResult Edita(string nome_filial)
    {
        Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
        Filial filial = new Filial();
        string comando = "SELECT A.FILIAL, B.VALOR_PROPRIEDADE FROM FILIAIS A " +
                         "LEFT JOIN PROP_FILIAIS B ON A.FILIAL = B.FILIAL AND B.PROPRIEDADE = '00814'" +
                         "WHERE A.FILIAL = @FILIAL";

        var parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"FILIAL", nome_filial}
        };
        var rows = conexao.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(comando, parametros);
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            filial.filial = row["FILIAL"];
            filial.estoque_max = row["VALOR_PROPRIEDADE"];
        }

        return View(filial);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edita(Filial filial) {

        return Content(filial.estoque_max.ToString() + filial.filial.ToString());
    }
```

VIEW:

```
@model MaxEstoqueFiliais.Models.Filial


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Filial</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.filial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.filial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.filial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.estoque_max, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.estoque_max, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.estoque_max, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Classe Filial:

```
public class Filial
{
    [DisplayName("Filial")]
    public string filial { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Estoque Máximo")]
    public string estoque_max { get; set; }
}
```

Por que esta ficando nulo o meu objeto filial, sendo que estou passando ele para a view?

Perceba que os dados são levados para a view: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguém consegue me ajudar? Ja fiz de tudo, fiz igual a outros projetos meus e nos outros projetos está dando certo, somente neste que não vai de jeito nenhum. E não tem lógica nenhuma!

Comment: Não sei se pode ser, é um achismo, mas sua propriedade chama-se filical e o objeto filial, talvez ele esteja se perdendo nisso

Comment: Adicione a classe `Filial` à pergunta

Comment: @Barbetta, vc não vai acreditar, mas eu reenomei para nome_filial na classe, e deu certo! Pqp (facepalm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme falei no comentário o problema era que você tinha uma propriedade chamada `filial` e sua action recebia um objeto com nome `filial`, isso fazia com que ele se perdesse. uma opção é mudar o nome do objeto, outra é mudar o nome da propriedade, fica a seu critério.

Se atente que em C# a conversão é as propriedades começarem com a primeira letra maiúscula, você pode ler mais no [*Capitalization Conventions*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions#capitalizing-compound-words-and-common-terms)

Answer (score 2):

Conforme o [Barbetta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/88361/barbetta) comentou, mudei a propriedade FILIAL na classe FILIAL para NOME_FILIAL, dessa vez dando certo

```
public class Filial
{
 [DisplayName("Filial")]
 public string nome_filial { get; set; }
 [DisplayName("Estoque Máximo")]
 public string estoque_max { get; set; }
}
```